# Matrix elements of angular momentum operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-spin, matrix-elements

I was reading about the matrix elements of the generalized angular momentum operator in my QM textbook, when I came upon the following passage:

> The matrix representation of $J_+$ follows. It is \begin{align*}(J_+)_{j'm',jm}&=\langle j'm'\mid J_+\mid jm\rangle\\&=\sqrt{j(j+1)-m(m+1)}\hbar\delta_{jj'}\delta_{m'm+1}.\end{align*}

Now, I understand why the $\delta_{jj'}\delta_{m'm+1}$ part is necessary, because the orthogonality of the spin eigenstates means that the inner product will be $0$ unless $j'=j$ and $m'=m+1$. But where did the $\sqrt{j(j+1)-m(m+1)}\hbar$ factor come from? My impression was that the eigenstates are normalized to unity, so that if $j'=j$ and $m'=m+1$, we have that $\langle j'm'\mid j'm'\rangle=1$, which would imply that the matrix elements are just $\delta_{jj'}\delta_{m'm+1}$. Can anyone tell me what I am missing here?

Comment: this is derived in pretty much any textbook.  can you point to an issue with any one derivation?

Comment: You *do* understand the action of [$J_+$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_operator#Angular_momentum), right?

Comment: Actually, I didn't realize that $J_+$ involved multiplying by a constant. Sorry about that!